# nth closest point with integer coordinates to a given point

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms

I am trying to find the nth closest point to a given point in 2 dimensions. The given point can have any coordinates, but the result must x and y coordinates that are integers.

It is possible to do this by finding all points within a radius of n (actually $\sqrt n$ or something), building a heap and searching for the n closest points, but is there a faster way to do this? I do not need the n closest points, only the nth closest.

Comment: An idea. The four closest points are the vertices of the square (on the integer lattice) containing the given point. Can you systematically spiral out from there to more distant points until you reached the $n$th? (I haven't thought through the geometry, so not posting as an answer.)

Comment: @Ethan That's not necessarily true. Consider a point very close to one of the vertices of the square. The diagonally opposite vertex is not the 4th closest lattice point.

Comment: And also the shape formed isn't usually a spiral, consider the point say (.15, .1) the closest point is (0, 0) then (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 1) etc. I think the 2-5th closest points will always be the 8 points surrounding the nearest point, but I don't know what order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the $n^{\text{th}}$ closest point, the obvious improvement to make is to still take the $\mathcal O(n)$ points within distance $\sqrt n$ of the given point, but then use a linear-time selection algorithm (e.g. [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)) to choose the $n^{\text{th}}$ value.

Beyond that, we can also make use of the fact that a circle of radius $r$ with integer center contains approximately $\pi r^2$ integer points, with error that Gauss bounded by $2\sqrt2 \pi r$ (the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem)) and that we now have slightly better bounds for.

So we can, fairly precisely, choose a circular region that's guaranteed to have $n$ integer points in it: e.g., the union of four circles centered at the four nearest integer points near the given point, with radius $r$ such that $\pi r^2 - 2\sqrt2 \pi r > n$. We can also, similarly, find a smaller region that's guaranteed to *not* contain the $n^{\text{th}}$ closest point, leaving probably $\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$ or so candidate points.

Unfortunately, while this may speed up our search, it won't push it below $\mathcal O(n)$ time complexity, because we still need to figure out exactly how many points in the smaller region we're throwing away before we can rank the actually-viable points.

But if we could exactly count the number of integer points in a circle of radius $r$ (we can even assume it has integer center) in time $o(r^2)$, then we could use this idea to speed up the algorithm even further.